# tableadapters issue with SelectCommandTimeout property c#

Tags: c#, tableadapter

I want to increase the time to retrieve data from my tableadapter. How do i set it? I tried using this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/TableAdaptrCommandTimeout.aspx

However, the _commandCollection.Length is set to null therefore i am unable to set the CommandTimeout

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the GetData() Method on your tableAdapter before you can set the timeout, othewise the SelectCommand will not have been initialized.

```
protected void setAdapterTimeout(SqlDataAdapter da, int timeOut = 120)
    {

        if (da.SelectCommand != null)
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = timeOut;

    }
```

Then call it like this:

```
 //Replacing AccessoryTableAdapter with your table Adapter
 AccessoryTableAdapter ata = new AccessoryTableAdapter();
 setAdapterTimeout(ata.Adapter);
```

**EDIT**: Extension Methods are cool!

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void setAdapterTimeout(this SqlDataAdapter da, int timeOut = 120)
    {
        if (da.SelectCommand != null)
            da.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = timeOut;
        if (da.InsertCommand != null)
            da.InsertCommand.CommandTimeout = timeOut;

    }
}
```

then call it:

```
 AccessoryTableAdapter ata = new AccessoryTableAdapter();
 ata.Adapter.setAdapterTimeout(120);
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this work correctly.
The only think is adding this row of code at the original *codeproject* solution:

```
if ((this._commandCollection == null)) this.InitCommandCollection();
```

So, the SelectCommandTimeout propery become:

```
    // Add this check before the assign step...
    if ((this._commandCollection == null)) this.InitCommandCollection();
    for (int i = 0; i < this._commandCollection.Length; i++)
    {
       if ((this._commandCollection[i] != null))
       {
          ((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)
          (this._commandCollection[i])).CommandTimeout = value;
       }
    }
   }
 }
```